# Client Application using Basic Auth with Spring Security and Keycloak

Tags: spring, spring-security, keycloak

I have an architecture where my user application wants to use a basic authentication when accessing a spring service. This service has to use a Keycloak instance to verify the user/pass of the user application. I don't succeed to configure it (and don't know if its possible).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Keycloak has Spring Security adapter that can be configured for Client and/or Resource Server.
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_spring_security_adapter 
And also a working example here:
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/app-authz-spring-security